# .NET Core Token authentication - body

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a custom authentication via JWT for a .NET Core Web API, but the requirement is that clients want to send the token in body of the HTTP request.

That is not a standard approach nor is this supported by .NET Core by default. Is there a way to get the token from a HTTP request body and use it for authentication.

What I have currently relies on `Request.EnableRewind()` and the use of `MemoryStream` to read from the body and then seek the start of body again so that it can be read by the controller later. That works perfectly fine, but if there are thousands of requests in a short timespan, the API's performance will decrease and that is not good.

Is there a good alternative to this approach?

```cs
services.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false, 
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
        {
            StringValues values;

            if (ctx.Request.Method.Equals("POST"))
            {
                ctx.Request.EnableRewind();
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ctx.Request.Body.CopyTo(ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    ctx.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        var jsonBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseRequest>(jsonBody);
                        ctx.Token = body.Token;
                        ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {body.Token}";
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for an alternative approach to using `MemoryStream`, you could use `Request.EnableBuffering()`, perhaps. I would suggest checking "[Re-reading ASP.Net Core request bodies with EnableBuffering()](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/re-reading-asp-net-core-request-bodies-with-enablebuffering/)" out over on devblogs.microsoft.com...

Essentially, your `OnMessageReceived` would look something like this:

```cs
if (ctx.Request.Method.Equals("POST")
{
    ctx.Request.EnableBuffering();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, $YOURBUFFERSIZE$, true))
    {
        var jsonBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseRequest>(jsonBody);
        if (body != null)
        {
            ctx.Token = body.Token;
            ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {body.Token}";
            ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, this itself is not the best way to do it, but if you really want to avoid modifying anything other than your `OnMessageReceived`, I guess this method doesn't require the use of `MemoryStream`.